# iPerf3 - normal and reverse measurement in the same instance

Tags: networking, iperf

I can start a normal measurement (with 192.168.1.2 being the server) with

```
iperf3 -c 192.168.1.2
```

and a reverse measurement with

```
iperf3 -c 192.168.1.2 -R
```

Is there any way I can do both a normal and a reverse measurement one after another without having to start it twice, so both in the same instance?